# What's the meaning of "beyond the apparent demands"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

> This past Saturday, I spent hours photographing some of the 14,000
>   peaceful antigovernment protestors. It took me back to my experiences
>   at the demonstrations over the lifting of the ban on U.S. imported
>   beef after a case of mad cow disease in 2008. In both cases, there was
>   much going on, **beyond the apparent demands**.

link: http://koreajoongangdaily.joins.com/news/article/Article.aspx?aid=3012538

What's the meaning of "beyond the apparent demands" in this article?

I searched the meaning of 'demand' in the dictionary, and
I'm not sure which one suits in the context above.

> 6.the act of demanding.
>
> 7.something that is demanded.
>
> 8.an urgent or pressing requirement:demands upon one's time.
>
> 9.Economics.the desire to purchase, coupled with the power to do so.the quantity of goods that buyers will take at a particular price.
>
> 10.a requisition; a legal claim:The demands of the client could not be met.
>
> 11.the state of being wanted or sought for purchase or use:an article in great demand.
>
> 12.Archaic. inquiry; question.

Source: dictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the **demands** were conditions what the protestors were seeking and they were trying to make them as **visible** or **apparent** as possible. These would be the

> **apparent demands**

**Beyond the apparent demands** means additional elements may be at play. These are sometimes referred to as

> **beneath the surface**
>   **subtexts**
>   **multiple moving parts**

So possibly, the **specific** protest for the beef ban lifting was about US beef, however the **subtext** may have been **other fears** of greater competition across many other industries in general.

The phrase is not about **the demands** *per se*, but using the demands as a **frame of reference**.